# How to insert something into a table when another table holds a specific value using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that consists of two tables, which look like this:

users

---

userID (PK) | email | password |

---

photos

---

photoID (PK) | userID (FK) | directory|

---

I want to insert a directory path into directory where the userID in users is say 1.

I was checking out SQL on the w3schools but I didn't know what this type of query is called.

Can anyone suggest the SQL I need to accomplish this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO photos (userID, directory) VALUES("1", "<your directory>");
```

or if you actually want to change the directory

```
UPDATE photos SET directory = "<your directory>" WHERE userId = "1";
```

Comment: Thanks. How does the query know I am referring to userID from the users table and not the foreign Key userID in the photos table? Which is what I want to do.

Comment: Because you presumably created the table photos with `FOREIGN KEY userId REFERENCES user.userId`. As they are both `1` I don't see your problem here.

Comment: I think you'r misunderstanding foreign keys. A foreign key is just a constraint that has your transactions fail if you try to break it. For instance if you tried to insert a photo for a `userId` `-1`, which does not exist, the foreign key constant will fail and abort your query with an error. The actual values in your tables `user` and `photo` are no references, but copies.

Comment: Thank you that works, I don't know why I was trying to do something in such a complicated way.

Answer (score -1):

Try something along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO photos SELECT 0, userID, 'directory_path' FROM users WHERE userID = 1
```

Comment: Docs on this syntax for MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

Comment: It doesn't make sense to select userID when you are passing it the userID anyway. The SELECT statement is redundant and just makes the query inefficient, and confusing to look at.

Comment: Perhaps, but this is just a simple example. The WHERE statement could be something more involved like 'WHERE userID > 0 AND userID < 5'.